# Python3 Uniquify list of tuples based on only one of the values of the index

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I swear I searched SO first, and found a lot of "could-work-if-adapted" but nothing really helped me. What I have is a list of tuples in the form:

```py
[('', 'noreply@bookfresh.com'), ('Andrea', 'andrea@aaa.com'), ('Your Book', 'noreply@bookfresh.com'), ..]
```

In this case, it's a list of tuples that has a "Name" as the first value, and an "Email" as the second value, in all indexes. And list is not ordered in any particular way (yet).

What I need is a clean and understandable (I am not necessarily looking for one-liners that I can't even read) way to produce a "uniquified" list, but with these rules/caveats:

- Only remove a tuple if it finds a duplicate of the second value of the tuple (in this case, it happens to be an email address, and it would be "noreply@bookfresh.com")
- Don't eliminate all instances of duplicating tuples. I need to keep one, and the one to keep should be the tuple that has the most len() of the first object. (in this case, of the duplicate tuples, it would keep only the tuple ('Your Book', 'noreply@bookfresh.com').

Final output in this minimized example would be:

```
[('Andrea', 'andrea@aaa.com'), ('Your Book', 'noreply@bookfresh.com'), ..]
```

It doesn't matter if output is not ordered or sorted since I know how to sort a list of unsorted tuples. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method #1: collect all the names

If we want the most understandable version, not the slickest, maybe something like

```
pairs = [('', 'noreply@bookfresh.com'), ('Andrea', 'andrea@aaa.com'), ('Your Book', 'noreply@bookfresh.com')]

data = {}
for name, email in pairs:
    if email not in data:
        data[email] = []
    data[email].append(name)

output = [(email, max(data[email], key=len)) for email in data]
```

would work.  This breaks the problem into two parts: building a dictionary with the email address as the key and a list of possible names as the values; and looping over all the email addresses and getting the longest name.

The first part could be condensed using `setdefault`, e.g.

```
for name, email in pairs:
    data.setdefault(email, []).append(name)
```

but not everyone's familiar with that.

---

Method #2: sort and make unique

Alternatively, we can sort by email and name length at once, and then build a dictionary from that which will only keep the last key/value pair seen:

```
>>> pairs.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], len(x[0])))
>>> data = {v: k for k,v in pairs}
>>> [(v,k) for k,v in data.items()]
[('Andrea', 'andrea@aaa.com'), ('Your Book', 'noreply@bookfresh.com')]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining both methods, it serves to imagine the problem trying to abstract oneself. I am implementing #2 though which did the work, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could build a dictionary using the second entry as your key. A dictionary has the propriety of not containing any duplicate in its keys. If you sort by the length of the first element before building your dictionary, it will provide you what you seek:

```
your_list_sorted = sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
out = dict((v, k) for k, v in your_list_sorted)
```

If you need your output in list form, you can do `out_list = list(out.items())` to get it.

Comment: I ended up using a similar method proposed by @DSM below, which uses Dictionary. In your case though, it reversed it so it was an extra step. But your answer apparently works too, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is using a set like this:

```
L = [('', 'noreply@bookfresh.com'), ('Andrea', 'andrea@aaa.com'), ('Your Book', 'noreply@bookfresh.com'), ..]

emails = set()

result_L = []

for item in L:
    if item[1] in emails:
        # this email address is already seen
        continue

    result_L += [item]
    emails.add(item[1])
```

However, if you wanted to keep the last item, you can use this (at last, you may want to reverse `result_L`):

```
for i in reversed(L):
    # ...
```

There are a lot of other ways to do this, too. For example, consider using a `dict`:

```
result_dict = {}

for item in L:
    result_dict[item[1]] = item[0]

result_L = [(y, x) for (x, y) in result_dict.items()]
```